# Why does ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 link against unexpected location?

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc, binutils

I have installed a new glibc in `/root/tools/` in debian which already has a pre-installed glibc. For testing the new glibc, I type :

```
gcc test.c -Wl,-rpath=/root/tools/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/root/tools/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

produces `a.out`, then type:

```
ldd a.out
```

it shows

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd1018c000)
libc.so.6 => /root/tools/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc7f468b000)
/root/tools/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc7f4855000)
```

But type `ls -l /root/tools/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` ,
it shows `/root/tools/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> ld-2.33.so`

Why does ld.so in new glibc link against ld.so in /lib64 ? How to explain this ?

Comment: The new glibc was built with the linker from the system binutils / the system glibc. ... I guess you will have to do like "Linux From Scratch" if you want a new independent tool-chain → https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> then type: `ldd a.out`.

When multiple GLIBC installations are present, you should stop using `ldd` -- it will lie to you.

Instead, do this:

```
env LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 ./a.out
```

That command will tell you what objects are *actually* loaded.

It looks like your setup is correct and you are simply mislead by `ldd`.

**Update:**

> Alternatively, using ldd which is in /root/tools/bin/ also displays right result

Yes, but that will display the wrong result for e.g. `/bin/date`, so that `ldd` will lie the *other way*.

If you already know which `ldd` is the right one to use, you can use it. Just be aware that using the "wrong" `ldd` will produce confusing output. Something `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS` doesn't suffer from.

Comment: Your command has a minor error ... It should be `env LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 ./a.out` . Alternatively, using ldd which is in `/root/tools/bin/` also displays right result  , as following(last line): `/root/tools/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /root/tools/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fedd635b000)`

Comment: @lgd I've corrected the typo and updated the answer.

Comment: In a system along with multiple glibcs, it seems that I should test the dependencys of a program by the `ldd` of the corresponding `glibc` which consists of the program . However , your way is the most surest .