# Ineffective to use patchelf to add a declared dependency on a dynamic library

Tags: linux, x86-64, elf, glibc

hello I am trying to use intel `mpiifort` to compile my program. One error occurs during make:

```
ld:xxx/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/bin/intel64/../../bin/intel64/../../lib/icx-lto.so: error loading plugin: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found.
```

I read this [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host/851229#851229) and I complied glibc-2.17 and patchelf both. Then I input

`patchelf --set-rpath xxx/glibc-2.17/lib/ xxx/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/lib/icx-lto.so`
and
`patchelf --add-needed xxx/glibc-2.17/lib/libc.so.6 xxx/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/lib/icx-lto.so`

The result of `ldd xxx/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/lib/icx-lto.so` is

> linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffaa5ff000)
>
> ```
>    libc.so.6 => xxx/glibc/glibc-2.17/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb1adff8000)
>    librt.so.1 => xxx/glibc/glibc-2.1/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007fb1addf0000)
>    libdl.so.2 => xxx/glibc/glibc-2.17/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb1adbec000)
>    libimf.so => xxx/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libimf.so (0x00007fb1ad563000)
>    libm.so.6 => xxx/glibc/glibc-2.17/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb1ad265000)
>    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fb1ad032000)
>    libsvml.so => xxx/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libsvml.so (0x00007fb1ab534000)
>    libirng.so => xxx/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libirng.so (0x00007fb1ab1ca000)
>    libgcc_s.so.1 => xxx/gcc-4.7.4/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb1aafb4000)
>    libintlc.so.5 => xxx/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libintlc.so.5 (0x00007fb1aad3b000)
>    libpthread.so.0 => xxx/glibc-2.17/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb1aab1e000)
>    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003b70a00000)
> ```

But it is still not working when I re-compile my program. Does anyone have some solutions?

Actually same errors when using `ifort` and `icc`. But it is solved by `patchelf --set-interpreter xxx/glibc/glibc-2.17-gcc-4.8.5/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --set-rpath xxx/glibc/glibc-2.17-gcc-4.8.5/lib/ xxx/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/bin/intel64/ifort`

Comment: Is it expected that your patched `icx-lto.so` still finds `/lib64/libz.so.1`?  I guess you don't have a `libz.so.1` in your `xxx/glibc/glibc-2.17/lib/`.  I guess that's probably fine, as long as libz doesn't try to resolve its own dependencies against /lib64/libc.so.1.  Also, isn't glib 2.14 pretty old?  Maybe time to upgrade to a newer version of your distro; current glibc is 2.33.

Comment: You should never use `ldd` on a machine with multiple GLIBCs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68251162/50617. Also, running `ldd` on the `.so` doesn't tell us what your _actual_ problem is (what does "not working" mean?).

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I think so. And I am using a cluster with CentOS 6.10, so I have to get adapted to it.

Comment: @EmployedRussian  Unfortunately, the result of `env LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 xxx/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/lib/icx-lto.so` is `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, so `patchelf` damaged this`.so`? 
P.S. "not working" means the problem remains the same.

Comment: You don't *have* to keep using an old CentOS install that's getting more and more obsolete every year.  It's already past it's EOL even for maintenance / security updates, and has been since last November (https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product), so it's *really* time to start thinking about either retiring the cluster or upgrading to a new version of something or a new distro.  Up to you if you want to spend more time futzing around with a new compiler on that old distro, but even CentOS 8 was 2015.

Comment: @EmployedRussian UPDATE, I tried other `.so` that I didn't modify, it still shows `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. it seems `env LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1` only works for app?

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for your advice anyway. You see, I don't have the right to make decision either to retire or upgrade the cluster. I am trying to use it because I want more computation resource. And I really doubt the one in charge of it will take the advice.

Comment: If you're not the admin, then sending them a request to get Intel's compiler installed for you might be useful (either in getting them to solve this, or getting them to finally upgrade).  If not, then good luck. :/

Comment: "env LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 only works for app?" -- yes, and you should set it for the `ifort` binary, so we can see what libraries _it_ loads.

Comment: @EmployedRussian `ifort` has loaded the libraries as it is supposed: 
````
linux-vdso.so.1 
libdl.so.2 => xxx/glibc/glibc-2.17-gcc-4.8.5/lib/libdl.so.2
libpthread.so.0 => xxx/glibc/glibc-2.17-gcc-4.8.5/lib/libpthread.so.0 
libstdc++.so.6 => xxx/gcc/gcc-4.7.4/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
libm.so.6 =>xxx/glibc/glibc-2.17-gcc-4.8.5/lib/libm.so.6 
libc.so.6 => xxx/glibc/glibc-2.17-gcc-4.8.5/lib/libc.so.6
xxx/glibc/glibc-2.17-gcc-4.8.5/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libgcc_s.so.1 =>xxx/gcc/gcc-4.7.4/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
````

Comment: "`ifort` loaded libraries as it is supposed to" -- so _what_ is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @EmployedRussian as I said above, this error information: ld:xxx/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/bin/intel64/../../bin/intel64/../../lib/icx-lto.so: error loading plugin: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found. Even though `ifort` and `icc` have loaded correct libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This errror:

```
ld: xxx/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/bin/intel64/.../icx-lto.so: error loading plugin: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found.
```

appears to be coming from `ld`.

> same errors when using `ifort` and `icc`

It looks like both `ifort` and `icc` are using *linker* plugin to perform LTO (link-time optimization).

You need to `patchelf` the binary which actually fails (`ld` in this case), *not* the binary which merely invokes `ld` (i.e. leave `ifort` and `icc` alone).

Usually you can tell the compiler to print more info about the binaries it invokes with e.g. `icc -v <rest of command>`.

I expect that there is `ld` (or possibly `ld.lld`) under `.../intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/...`, and you need to `patchelf` *that* binary.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem is caused by `ld` not icx-lto.so. And `ld` is actually an app from binutils. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @yiyuan -- if the answer helped you, upvote it. If it answered your question completely, accept it.